# singly linked list head and tail method?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm relatively new to c programming language, and was playing around to get familiar with it, but I'm not sure how to actually implement a linked list with the following structs and data I'm trying to do(below). Basically the goal is to add an item from a singly linked list with a head and tail.

Update: I tried to do write some code in my add function, haven't sorted it but is that how it would look like?

**CODE SOURCE**

```
typedef struct {
    char car_model[32],car_name[32];

} CarObjects;

typedef struct myNode{

    struct myNode* next;
    CarObjects* data;

} MyList;

//initialize list
void declareList(MyList* someList){
    someList->next = NULL;
}

void insertElementByTitle(MyList* someList, CarObjects* someCar){

    //first case adding to an empty list.
    if(someList == NULL){
        someList = malloc(sizeof(MyList));
        someList->data = someCar;
        someList->next = NULL;
    }
//END OF first case adding to an empty list.

//make thee list's head and tail node, point to the first element since its an empty list
    someList->head = someList;
    someList->tail = someList->head;


    while(someList->next != NULL)
       someList = someList->next;

    someList->next = malloc(sizeof(MyList));
    someList = someList->next;
    someList->data = newBook;
    someList->next = NULL;


}


int main(){


   MyList* listHead= NULL;
   MyList* listTail= NULL;


   //Somehow add an element to the list



   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you restricted to those structs for a reason?  Putting head and tail in every node is pretty horrible… much better to have one pointer to each in a container or global variable.  With your existing strucutres you'll have to iterate through the entire list to update pointers every time you modify the list…

Comment: To achieve "the goal is to add an item" _to_ "a singularly linked list with a head and tail." only takes a `typedef struct myNode{ 
    struct myNode* next;
    CarObjects* data;
} MyList;`.  Aside from adding to the list, what other functions are needed?

Comment: @chux there isnt much functions needed, all im trying to do is just add an item to to the linked list, and checking if we're adding an item at the beginning or middle or end of a list with head and tail

Comment: "just add an item to to the linked list," differs from "Add an element ... by ascending order of the cars names".  Does the add function need to maintain the sort?

Comment: yeah the add function should maintain the sort, it should know when its adding the car object, that this car that is being added, is in alphabetic ascending order

Comment: You would generally want them to be globals, so that `insertElementByTitle` would have access to them.  Or, better yet, `typedef struct CarNode_s { CarNode* head; CarNode* tail; } CarList`, `typedef struct CarNode_s { struct CarNode_s* next; CarObject* car; } CarNode;`, `void insertElementByTitle(CarList* someList, CarObject* someCar);`.

Comment: I'd also think about getting rid of the pointer for `CarObject` in `CarNode`, too (just make it a `CarNode` instead of a `CarNode*`, that way you have one less slice of memory to worry about.  Whether that's the right option or not depends on how you plan to use it, though…

Comment: I'm lost xd, I'm sure what to do no more.

Comment: Does your list need to be sorted?  If so, by what?

Comment: yes my list needs to be sorted by a car's name in alphabetic order, for example

toyota is added first to the list and then Honda. so the list should be re-ordered and Honda should be first then toyota

Comment: What algorithms and data structures do you want? It sounds like you are keeping a singly-linked list ordered on insertion, O(n). You will probably need a comparison function of the form `int compare(const struct Car *, const struct Car *)` which is called by the insertion function. The tail on a singly linked list is probably useless. Probably a good idea to simplify according to @nemequ and don't use `typedef struct`, it's confusing, `struct Car { char ... struct Car *next; };` is all you need.

Answer (score -1):

At first properly define your structure.

```
typedef struct car{
char car_model[32],car_name[32];
};

typedef struct myList{
myList * next;
car * carObject;
};
```

Now, you are trying to insert as the Insertion Sort technique.

```
void insertElementByTitle(MyList* someList, CarObjects* someCar){
\\I assume someList is pointing the head of the linked list
\\One more assumption that, the Linked List is already sorted and need to inset
\\someCar in the correct position.
MyList *secondPointer = someList->next;
while(secondPointer != null)
{
     if(ifCarIsInBetweenSomeListAndSecondPointer(someList,secondPointer,someCar))
     {
      someList->next = newNode(someCar);
      someList->next->next=secondPointer;
      break;
     }
  someList = secondPointer; secondPointer = secondPointer->next;
}
if(secondPointer == null)
{
     someList->next = newNode(someCar);
}
}
```

Now, you need two function

```
myNode* newNode(car * someCar);
bool ifCarIsInBetweenSomeListAndSecondPointer(myNode *someList,myNode *secondPointer,car *someCar);

myNode* newNode(car * someCar){
myNode * t =(struct myNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct myNode));
t->carObject = someCar;
t->next= null;
return t;
}

bool ifCarIsInBetweenSomeListAndSecondPointer(myNode *someList,myNode *secondPointer,car *someCar){
if( (strcmp(someList->carObject->car_name,someCar->carObject)<0) &&(strcmp(someCar->carObject,secondPointer->carObject->car_name)<0))
          return true;
return false;
}
```

Refer online reference such as [geeksforgeeks-linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/), to get better understanding.